# Custom table for store multiple values in cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to make custom table for scheduling with rows with persons and columns with days.
Additional logic will be implemented to fill cells. 
Every cell hold information about who is engagement in particular day in particular shift (it can be more shift).

Actually, I need a way to store values in some control(maybe my custom html tag, for example 
), hidden field or something. After schedule same cell will
be filled with additional data (achieved date time start, achieved date time end).

Final step will be to take all values and store to database.

What you think about that? Have you some advice or similar case?

Comment: ..and you need to try it first. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with values putted in ID field. Custom function parse same ID field and extract necessary values.

Answer (score 0):

U mean Like Create The Table In The Run Time 
If So I Think This Code Will Help You

```
   var Products = response.value;
            var s = new Array();
            s[s.length] = "<table id='Productss' border = 1 bgcolor='Grey'>";
            s[s.length] = "<th>" + "Product ID" + "</th>";
            s[s.length] = "<th>" + "Product Name" + "</th>";
            s[s.length] = "<th>" + "Unit" + "</th>";
            s[s.length] = "<th>" + "Reorder Level" + "</th>";
            s[s.length] = "<th>" + "Supplier Name" + "</th>";
            s[s.length] = "<th>" + "Unit Price" + "</th>";
            s[s.length] = "<th>" + "Units In Stock" + "</th>";
            s[s.length] = "<th>" + "Units On Order" + "</th>";
            for (var i = 0; i < Products.length; i++) {
                s[s.length] = "<tr>";
                s[s.length] = "<td>" + Products[i].ProductID + "</td>";
                s[s.length] = "<td>" + Products[i].ProductName + "</td>";
                s[s.length] = "<td>" + Products[i].UnitName + "</td>";
                s[s.length] = "<td>" + Products[i].ReorderLevel + "</td>";
                s[s.length] = "<td>" + Products[i].SupplierID + "</td>";
                s[s.length] = "<td>" + Products[i].UnitPrice + "</td>";
                s[s.length] = "<td>" + Products[i].UnitsInStock + "</td>";
                s[s.length] = "<td>" + Products[i].UnitsOnOrder + "</td>";
                s[s.length] = "</tr>";
            }
            s[s.length] = "</table>";
            document.getElementById("DisplayResult").innerHTML = s.join("");


    }
```

var Products Its Avariable Describes The Return Of Ajax Method And I Draw Table with JAvascript And Join It In span And Thats The Code Of joining

```
   document.getElementById("DisplayResult").innerHTML = s.join("");
```

Let Me Know If Any Thing Not Clear

Comment: My table will bi filled via some jquery functions and values will be saved via AJAX. Values my not be visible.